# Github Work Flow for Fork

Tags: git, github

What am I missing that is so blatantly obvious here?

I want to contribute to a fork of a main project on github, however when I use the github UI to fork the repo it forks the main project and not the fork I want to contribute to.

The reason I want to contribute to the fork is it uses a different billing system that is already configured so it doesn't make sense for me to fork the original project which uses the "other" payment system. In theory I want to-

- Fork this repo https://github.com/siddarth/selfstarter-stripe
- make my changes and submit a pull request to the forked project.

However, when I attempt to use the UI to fork, it returns the fork of the original project (with non preferred pmt system). What am I missing here, I'm sure this happens all the time but searching around I haven't found the intended method of performing this.

Comment: I was able to fork the fork just fine. I pushed the fork button on the page at the url you gave. What button are you using? Are you sure that you're not forking the repo you want to fork?

Comment: What is "github UI"? A desktop application? On which OS? Which version? The `Fork` button on GitHub website works as expected.

Comment: @cupcake when I click the fork button on the url provided I get the redirected to my repo when I forked the main project initially. Perhaps this is because I already forked the main project? Would that make sense as it wouldn't understand that I want to fork the other project? Just using the regular form button under the sign out icon

Comment: @janos when I say github ui I'm referring to the github web app as opposed to performing any of these operations from the command line. So are you guys not able to fork the main project then (given my comment above)? I'll look to test this on github another account.

Comment: If I fork the main project at https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter, then GitHub won't let me do another fork of https://github.com/siddarth/selfstarter-stripe. Why not just add the second repo as a remote, fetch siddarth's branches, do your changes, push to your own fork (of the main repo), and then do a pull request against siddarth's fork? I've never tried that with public repos, but that's the way my team at work uses a bunch of private forks of a main project, we can send pull requests against any of the other forks.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. I guess I was just thrown off by the web app implementation didn't work as I would have expected. Thanks for your attention. Can you repost so I can mark as answer?

Comment: @Tmacram please also consider upvoting if you think my answer deserves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158706/github-work-flow-for-fork?noredirect=1#comment26601057_18158706), you could just fork the main project at https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter, then add [siddarth's fork](https://github.com/siddarth/selfstarter-stripe) as a remote and fetch his branches. When you're done working on a branch based off of his changes, push the work to your own private fork.

I'm not sure if GitHub will let you send a pull request to siddarth's fork, but GitHub does have that feature at least for people working in organizations.

If it turns out that you can't send a pull request through GitHub directly to siddarth's fork, then you can do it manually using [`git request-pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-request-pull.html) and sending the output as an email to siddarth ([the process is explained in further detail in the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project)):

```
git request-pull <start-commit> <url-of-your-remote-fork> > pull-request.txt
```

Also, you could just contact siddarth and ask him to check out the changes in your remote fork that way (he could just fetch them).

Of course, the disadvantage of not using GitHub's pull-request functionality is that you don't get the built-in code reviewing system attached to the pull-request.